# Why did Sauron flee from Dol Guldur when Gandalf first entered?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

Did the Dark Lord feel that even Gandalf the Grey was too much for him to deal with at the time or was he simply fleeing to cover up his identity?

Comment: According to the Tolkien Gateway site; "The Council of the Wise long feared the Necromancer might indeed be Sauron, and in 2063 Gandalf went to Dol Guldur, and Sauron, **not yet powerful**, fled to the East."

Comment: From the Hobbit "*It was in this way that he learned where Gandalf had been to; for he overheard the words of the wizard to Elrond. It appeared that Gandalf had been to a great council of the white wizards, masters of lore and good magic; and that they had at last driven the Necromancer from his dark hold in the south of Mirkwood.*"

Comment: @Richard - I'm reading "when Gandalf first entered" as being his visit in TA 2063, ~900 years before the White Council attack during the events of the Hobbit.

Comment: @darthsatan - Hence why I posted it as a comment. It's relevant that Sauron is scared of the White Council.

Answer (score 10):

The Tale of Years entry for TA 2063 describes Sauron's retreat from Dol Guldur as follows:

> Gandalf goes to Dol Guldur. Sauron retreats and hides in the East. The Watchful Peace begins.

Earlier in Appendix A the Watchful Peace is described:

> At first they had quiet, for those were the days of the Watchful Peace, **during which Sauron withdrew before the power of the White Council** and the Ringwraiths remained hidden in Morgul Vale.

It's obvious therefore that at this time Sauron wasn't powerful enough to resist the White Council.

Comment: All quotes from Lord of the Rings.

Comment: Dangit. You keep taking my answers. You must be in the wrong time zone. Never mind, I'll make it up this afternoon. Hahahahaha!

Answer (score 3):

To fully answer this you need to consult The Silmarillion, which is Tolkien's world history of Middle Earth.  As @Darth Satan said, the White Council drove Sauron away, but the council was deadlocked on the issue (Saruman insisting on containment/observation) until Gandalf conclusively proved the Necromancer **was** Sauron in disguise.

At that time, the White Council fought Sauron, but he merely pretended to flee, and instead traveled to Mordor, where the Nazgûl had been prepping everything for Sauron.

Sauron, even though he was originally just a servant of The Great Enemy, was still more powerful than the Wizards, who themselves were servants of the Valar, The Creator's Designated Caretakers of Middle Earth.  The inference is that the Istari were "3rd-tier" spirits, with the Valar and Melkor (The Great Enemy) being 1st-tier, and Sauron being 2nd-tier. So, the Wizards couldn't go one-on-one with Sauron, but they could greatly assist the elves, humans and dwarves in resisting.  The High Elves, naturally, recognized the wizards for what they were, which is why Cirdan the Shipwright gave the Elven ring of Fire to Gandalf.

Comment: Melkor/Morgoth *was also* a Vala: "**Melkor** The Quenya name for **the great rebellious Vala**, the beginning of evil, in his origin the mightiest of the Ainur;"—Tolkeins Sr. and Jr. in "The Index of Names" from The Silmarillion. Emphasis added.

Comment: @Lexible: Yes, you are correct. Sorry about that, and thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If he left Dol Guldur, then Sauron fled. If he pretended to flee, he would have still been there.  He may have been able to win if he had not fled, but he did not try.

Comment: Sauron and the Istari were both Maia, and thus "second tier" spirits.  There is no real third tier, or this third tier are Men and Elves.

Comment: No,  Sauron did fight. In the third movie you will see the White Council mount an offensive.  It wasn't until his imprisonment in LOTR that Gandalf finally put it all together.

Comment: However.  You are correct about them all being Maia. It has been over a decade since I last read the Sil. I think I was confusing the hierarchy a bit.  Some of the maia were more powerful than others. My understanding is that the Istari were minor Maia

Comment: @oldcat. Sorry to be dense. I get what you were saying.  I would have been better to have said pretended to be beaten.  Rather than "pretended to flee". This has not been one of my best days.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The istari are indeed Maia. However, they are somewhat stripped of their powers. They are put on Middle-Earth to guide the mortal races, not to fight evil stuff themselves.

Comment: @ThorinSchmidt: Gandalf certainly wasn't a 'minor' Maïa, since he was the wisest of the Maïar and is asked by Manwë himself to be one of the wizards as is told in "Of the Istari" in Unfinished Tales.

Answer (score 0):

The White Council originally suspected 'The Necromancer' was in reality a ringwraith - a worrying enough fact if it had proven to be true.  Gandalf had quite a hard time in the dungeons of Dol Guldur as it was, but Sauron nevertheless fled because he did not want his true identity to be revealed to The Wise at that point.